# Is the tendon width determined by genetic predisposition, and if so, is genetics the sole factor?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, tendons

Tendons' widths vary widely across humans. E.g.:

- {1}: "the mean patellar tendon width was 26.10mm (SD = 3.31; range 18.33mm-33.33mm)"
- {2}: "Size of the patellar tendon width, measured at the same location in each patient, ranged from 24 to 35 mm"

Is the tendon width determined by genetic predisposition, and if so, is genetics the sole factor?

I read on {3}:

> Tendon length is determined by genetic predisposition, and has not been shown to either increase or decrease in response to environment, unlike muscles, which can be shortened by trauma, use imbalances and a lack of recovery and stretching.{4}

But it didn't mention the tendon width.

---

References:

- {1} Dundon, J. M., R. J. Markert, and M. W. Lawless. "Correlation between patella and patellar tendon width: an anatomic study." Clinical Anatomy 25, no. 3 (2012): 398-400. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21853464; https://doi.org/10.1002/ca.21241
- {2} Shelbourne, K. Donald, Richard A. Rubinstein JR, Charles D. VanMeter, John R. McCarroll, and Arthur C. Rettig. "Correlation of remaining patellar tendon width with quadriceps strength after autogenous bone-patellar tendon-bone anterior cruciate ligament reconstruction." The American journal of sports medicine 22, no. 6 (1994): 774-778. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7856801; https://doi.org/10.1177/036354659402200608
- {3} https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tendon&oldid=885716020
- {4} Young, Michael. "A Review on Postural Realignment and its Muscular and Neural Components" http://www.elitetrack.com/article_files/posture.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190406231332/http://www.elitetrack.com/article_files/posture.pdf))

Comment: My best guess is "We don't know. No study has investigated this question. However, given that tendon length has a non-zero heritability and given that a lot of bone, muscle and tendon properties are heritable <insert list of references>, it is probably safe to assume that tendon width is somewhat heritable."

Comment: @Remi.b Makes sense,  thanks for the feedback!